# How can I change from LINQ to using a simple foreach when comparing two collections?

Tags: c#

I have the following code which I find very confusing. What the code does is it compares the data from two collections and then issues an update, add or delete based on what has changed between oldObj and newObj.

Is there a way that I could simplify this so that it was all just contained in three foreach loops and so I did not have to use the fancy LINQ code. If someone could give me a suggestion on how I could do the first change with just additions then even that would be a great help.

```
var oldObj = db.SubTopics
  .Where(t => t.TopicId == id)
  .AsNoTracking()
  .ToList();
var newObj = topic.SubTopics.ToList();

var upd = newObj
  .Where(wb => oldObj
    .Any(db1 => (db1.SubTopicId == wb.SubTopicId) &&
      (db1.Number != wb.Number || !db1.Name.Equals(wb.Name)
      || !db1.Notes.Equals(wb.Notes))))
    .ToList();

var add = newObj
  .Where(wb => oldObj
    .All(db1 => db1.SubTopicId != wb.SubTopicId))
  .ToList();

var del = oldObj
  .Where(db1 => newObj
    .All(wb => wb.SubTopicId != db1.SubTopicId))
  .ToList();

foreach (var subTopic in upd)
{
  db.SubTopics.Attach(subTopic);
  db.Entry(subTopic).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
foreach (var subTopic in add)
{
  db.SubTopics.Add(subTopic);
}
foreach (var subTopic in del)
{
  db.SubTopics.Attach(subTopic);
  db.SubTopics.Remove(subTopic);
}
```

Comment: Which aspect of the required `foreach` statements confuses you?

Comment: Well, for a start, it would be much more readable if it used the built in LINQ keywords such as `from` and `where`.

Comment: It seems to be the linq he finds confusing. @wiz3kid: That's debatable. It'd be more readable to a DBA, but a programmer should understand method syntax.

Comment: It seems that this is Linq-To-Sql or Linq-To-Entities, isn't it?

Comment: It's not the foreach that's confusing. What I would like to know is if there is a way I could combine the LINQ and the foreach into one and do these at the same time. I would be okay if it took a couple more lines in the foreach but as it is now it just appears so unclear to me.

Comment: @Magus Which is fair enough. However, the conditions are simple comparisons, and the OP knows the solution is to use `foreach`. So on the face of things it should be a case of writing `foreach` statements and simply copying the conditions being checked.

Comment: @DanielKelley - If this was done then do you think it would look a bit more clear. I think the LINQ looks very cool but might not be as clear as a simple foreach.

Comment: @marifemac: no, you cannot combine them since LIN-Q- is for queries and the `foreach` is for modifications like insert, update or delete.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - But would it not be possible to just do a foreach on the old and inside check the new. Then do a foreach on the new and check the old topics and then have the insert, delete or update coded inside them?

Comment: One thing that might help is if you put the linq with the relevant foreach, and maybe even extracted the linq bits into methods.

Comment: @Tim - This is linq to entities with Entity Framework 6

Comment: @marifemac No, that would *not* be possible, or rather, it wouldn't be equivalent.  Currently the LINQ code is all translated into SQL and executed against the database.  What you are suggesting would mean pulling down the entire data sets into memory and doing all of the work on those in memory collections, which is radically changing what the code would be doing, not just how it reads.

Comment: @Servy I think that `.ToList()` calls already cause executing the query and loading data into memory.

Comment: @qbik Yeah, he should really remove that, as there is no compelling reason to do all of this work in memory, although he is doing some of the work using EF.

Comment: @Servy the only bit executed in the database in the code here is `Where(t => t.TopicId == id)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. Let’s simplify what you have first by removing any cruft. You’ve got some `.ToList()` calls for collections that are only ever used once, so they’re just extra code that do nothing but waste time and memory. Let’s cut them out as distractions:

```
var oldObj = db.SubTopics
    .Where(t => t.TopicId == id)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
var newObj = topic.SubTopics.ToList();

var upd = newObj
    .Where(wb => oldObj
        .Any(db1 => (db1.SubTopicId == wb.SubTopicId) &&
            (db1.Number != wb.Number || !db1.Name.Equals(wb.Name)
            || !db1.Notes.Equals(wb.Notes))));

var add = newObj
    .Where(wb => oldObj
        .All(db1 => db1.SubTopicId != wb.SubTopicId));

var del = oldObj
    .Where(db1 => newObj
        .All(wb => wb.SubTopicId != db1.SubTopicId));

foreach (var subTopic in upd)
{
    db.SubTopics.Attach(subTopic);
    db.Entry(subTopic).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
foreach (var subTopic in add)
{
    db.SubTopics.Add(subTopic);
}
foreach (var subTopic in del)
{
    db.SubTopics.Attach(subTopic);
    db.SubTopics.Remove(subTopic);
}
```

Now let’s move them into the bodies of the `foreach`:

```
var oldObj = db.SubTopics
    .Where(t => t.TopicId == id)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
var newObj = topic.SubTopics.ToList();

foreach (var subTopic in newObj
    .Where(wb => oldObj
        .Any(db1 => (db1.SubTopicId == wb.SubTopicId) &&
            (db1.Number != wb.Number || !db1.Name.Equals(wb.Name)
            || !db1.Notes.Equals(wb.Notes)))))
{
    db.SubTopics.Attach(subTopic);
    db.Entry(subTopic).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
foreach (var subTopic in newObj
    .Where(wb => oldObj
        .All(db1 => db1.SubTopicId != wb.SubTopicId)))
{
    db.SubTopics.Add(subTopic);
}
foreach (var subTopic in oldObj
    .Where(db1 => newObj
        .All(wb => wb.SubTopicId != db1.SubTopicId)))
{
    db.SubTopics.Attach(subTopic);
    db.SubTopics.Remove(subTopic);
}
```

Now let’s make the `.Where()` part of the `foreach` logic:

```
var oldObj = db.SubTopics
    .Where(t => t.TopicId == id)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
var newObj = topic.SubTopics.ToList();

foreach (var subTopic in newObj)
{
    if(oldObj.Any(db1 => (db1.SubTopicId == subTopic.SubTopicId) &&
            (db1.Number != subTopic.Number || !db1.Name.Equals(subTopic.Name)
            || !db1.Notes.Equals(subTopic.Notes))))
    {
        db.SubTopics.Attach(subTopic);
        db.Entry(subTopic).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }
}
foreach (var subTopic in newObj)
{
    if(oldObj.All(db1 => db1.SubTopicId != subTopic.SubTopicId))
    {
        db.SubTopics.Add(subTopic);
    }
}
foreach (var subTopic in oldObj)
{
    if(newObj.All(subTopic.SubTopicId != db1.SubTopicId))
    {
        db.SubTopics.Attach(subTopic);
        db.SubTopics.Remove(subTopic);
    }
}
```

Now let’s implement `.Any()` as a loop:

```
var oldObj = db.SubTopics
    .Where(t => t.TopicId == id)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
var newObj = topic.SubTopics.ToList();

foreach (var subTopic in newObj)
{
    foreach(var db1 in oldObj)
    {
        if((db1.SubTopicId == subTopic.SubTopicId) &&
            (db1.Number != subTopic.Number || !db1.Name.Equals(subTopic.Name)
            || !db1.Notes.Equals(subTopic.Notes)))
        {
            db.SubTopics.Attach(subTopic);
            db.Entry(subTopic).State = EntityState.Modified;
            break;
        }
    }
}
foreach (var subTopic in newObj)
{
    foreach(var db1 in oldObj)
    {
        if(db1 => db1.SubTopicId != subTopic.SubTopicId)
        {
            db.SubTopics.Add(subTopic);
            break;
        }
    }
}
foreach (var subTopic in oldObj)
{
    if(newObj.All(subTopic.SubTopicId != db1.SubTopicId)))
    {
        db.SubTopics.Attach(subTopic);
        db.SubTopics.Remove(subTopic);
    }
}
```

Now let’s do the same for `All()`:

```
var oldObj = db.SubTopics
    .Where(t => t.TopicId == id)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
var newObj = topic.SubTopics.ToList();

foreach (var subTopic in newObj)
{
    foreach(var db1 in oldObj)
    {
        if((db1.SubTopicId == subTopic.SubTopicId) &&
            (db1.Number != subTopic.Number || !db1.Name.Equals(subTopic.Name)
            || !db1.Notes.Equals(subTopic.Notes)))
        {
            db.SubTopics.Attach(subTopic);
            db.Entry(subTopic).State = EntityState.Modified;
            break;
        }
    }
}
foreach (var subTopic in newObj)
{
    foreach(var db1 in oldObj)
    {
        if(db1 => db1.SubTopicId != subTopic.SubTopicId)
        {
            db.SubTopics.Add(subTopic);
            break;
        }
    }
}
foreach (var subTopic in oldObj)
{
    bool allMatch = true;
    foreach(var db1 in newObj)
    {
        if(subTopic.SubTopicId != db1.SubTopicId)
        {
            allMatch = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(allMatch)
    {
        db.SubTopics.Attach(subTopic);
        db.SubTopics.Remove(subTopic);
    }
}
```

Finally, let’s get rid of the Linq from the initial list constructions. Note though that because this is linq-to-entities rather than linq-to-objects, we’re moving work that was in the database into memory, so this bit is a major performance killer. Really, it would be better to replace this with a call into a procedure that does what the `Where` was doing, but here we go:

```
var oldObj = new List<SubTopic>();
foreach(var t in db.SubTopics.AsNoTracking())
    if(t => t.TopicId == id)
        oldObj.Add(t);
var newObj = new List<SubTopic>(topic.SubTopics);

foreach (var subTopic in newObj)
{
    foreach(var db1 in oldObj)
    {
        if((db1.SubTopicId == subTopic.SubTopicId) &&
            (db1.Number != subTopic.Number || !db1.Name.Equals(subTopic.Name)
            || !db1.Notes.Equals(subTopic.Notes)))
        {
            db.SubTopics.Attach(subTopic);
            db.Entry(subTopic).State = EntityState.Modified;
            break;
        }
    }
}
foreach (var subTopic in newObj)
{
    foreach(var db1 in oldObj)
    {
        if(db1 => db1.SubTopicId != subTopic.SubTopicId)
        {
            db.SubTopics.Add(subTopic);
            break;
        }
    }
}
foreach (var subTopic in oldObj)
{
    bool allMatch = true;
    foreach(var db1 in newObj)
    {
        if(subTopic.SubTopicId != db1.SubTopicId)
        {
            allMatch = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(allMatch)
    {
        db.SubTopics.Attach(subTopic);
        db.SubTopics.Remove(subTopic);
    }
}
```

We are now 100% Linq-free. I do not think this has been an improvement in readability.

Generally if you want to improve readability, you can do well to break things down into methods, and to add comments at the points where something does not seem to be clear:

```
private static bool WasUpdated(SubTopic topic, IEnumerable<SubTopic> oldSubTopics)
{
    //Find all the subtopics in the old sub topics with the same subtopic id:
    var sameID = oldSubTopics.Where(db1 => db1.SubTopicId == topic.SubTopicId);
    //If there are any here that don’t match on number, name and notes, then they have changed:
    return sameID.Any(db1 => db1.Number != topic.Number || !db1.Name.Equals(topic.Name) || !db1.Notes.Equals(topic.Notes));

    //Note, if there can be only one subtopic with a given ID, then we would be both clearer and fastere with:
    var oldTopic = oldSubTopics.FirstOrDefault(db1 => db1.SubTopicId == topic.SubTopicId);
    return oldTopic != null &&
        (oldTopic.Number != topic.Number || !oldTopic.Name.Equals(topic.Name) || !oldTopic.Notes.Equals(topic.Notes));
}
private static bool WasAdded(SubTopic topic, IEnumerable<SubTopic> oldSubTopics)
{
    //If there’s no matching topic here, it was added.
    return !oldSubTopics.Any(old => old.SubTopicId == topic.SubTopicID);
}
private static bool WasRemoved(SubTopic topic, IEnumerable<SubTopic> newSubTopics)
{
    //If there’s no matching topic here, it was removed.
    return !newSubTopics.Any(newST => newST.SubTopicId == topic.SubTopicID);
}
```

Now we can call these in some smaller, code:

```
var dbSubTopics = db.SubTopics;
var oldObj = dbSubTopics
    .Where(t => t.TopicId == id)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToList();
var newObj = topic.SubTopics.ToList();

foreach (var subTopic in newObj.Where(st => WasUpdated(st, oldObj))
{
    dbSubTopics.Attach(subTopic);
    db.Entry(subTopic).State = EntityState.Modified;
}
dbSubTopics.AddRange(newObj.Where(st => WasAdded(st, oldObj));
foreach (var subTopic in oldObj.Where(st => WasRemoved(st, newObj))
{
    db.SubTopics.Attach(subTopic);
    db.SubTopics.Remove(subTopic);
}
```

There’s a degree of taste as to just how much to split something into methods and how much to use temporaries, but I think the above, which is if anything even Linq-ier than the original, is more readable.

It **might** be a good idea to remove the `ToList()` on `oldObj` and `newObj` and change the methods taking `IEnumerable<>` to take `IQueryable<>`. It might not either because of the same sets being hit multiple times, so it's not a no-brainer like it is in a lot of similar cases, but it's certainly worth taking a look at.

Comment: Thanks so much. One small question. Can you explain what you mean when you say "change the methods taking IEnumerable<> to take IQueryable<>". Which methods are you referring to ?

Comment: I'm on a phone now, and will be busy for the rest of the day, but I'll add something on that over the weekend.

Answer (score 2):

The conversion of `Where` to `foreach` is pretty straightforward, as mentioned in the comments.

The first two linq queries (`oldObj` and `newObj` variables) are just selecting data from database, they have to remain the same. `ToList() at the end means that we are executing the query against the database and actually retrieving the data.

The first expression:

```
var upd = newObj
  .Where(wb => oldObj
    .Any(db1 => (db1.SubTopicId == wb.SubTopicId) &&
      (db1.Number != wb.Number || !db1.Name.Equals(wb.Name)
      || !db1.Notes.Equals(wb.Notes))))
    .ToList();
```

Means "Get me objects from `newObj` collection that are also in `oldObj` and at least one of their properties have changed". Using `foreach`, it would be:

```
var upd = new List<SubTopic>();
foreach(var newObjElement in newObj) {
    bool wasUpdated = false;
    foreach(var oldObjEl in oldObj) {
        if (oldObjEl.SubTopicId == wb.SubTopicId 
           &&  (db1.Number != wb.Number || !db1.Name.Equals(wb.Name)
           || !db1.Notes.Equals(wb.Notes))) {
            wasUpdated = true;
            break;
        }
        if (wasUpdated) upd.Add(newObjElement);
    }
}
```

And this one:

```
var add = newObj
  .Where(wb => oldObj
    .All(db1 => db1.SubTopicId != wb.SubTopicId))
  .ToList();
```

becomes:

```
var add = new List<SubTopic>();
foreach(var newObjElement in newObj) {
    bool wasAdded = true;
    foreach(var oldObjEl in oldObj) {
        if (oldObjEl.SubTopicId != wb.SubTopicId) {
            // do nothing
        }
        else {
            wasAdded = false;
            break;
        }

        if (wasAdded) add.Add(newObjElement);
    }
}
```

and `del` is analogical to `add`.

Although such conversion is possible, I would highly discourage that. The `linq` version is really more readable. That's what `linq` was designed for.